# assertions using for loop in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to assert the boolean value true/false to check the status of checkbox using for loop.The loop runs for the first time and later fails for the second time.I checked in the UI and all the check boxes are checked(true).Please help me out how should I iterate to check all the status of the checkboxes.Below is the piece of code which I have tried

```
for (int i = 2; i < RowCount; i++)
{
    //checkaftersave = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[" + i + "]/input")).Selected;
    Assert.AreEqual(_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[" + i + "]/input")).Selected, "true");
}
```

Comment: Need to know how the html looks like as well

Comment: I don't see a problem.